# jQuery filtering age between age

Tags: jquery, select, filtering

How can i make it so people can filter between ages? So i can use the selectbox and that one will show everywone between 18 and 25 or 26 and 35 and so on?

Now i use this JS code for filtering:

```
jQuery("select.filterby").change(function() {
    var filters = jQuery.map(jQuery("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
        return jQuery(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    jQuery("div#holder-box").find(".box").hide(0);
    jQuery("div#holder-box").find(".box." + filters).show(0)
});
```

And the HTML is like:

```
<select class="filterby">
    <option value="all">All ages</option>
    <option value="18-25">18 to 25</option>
    <option value="25-35">26 to 35</option>
    <option value="36-45">36 to 45</option>
    <option value="46-55">46 to 55</option>
    <option value="56-65">56 to 65</option>
</select>

<select class="filterby">
    <option value="all">Show all</option>
    <option value="glasses">Glasses</option>
    <option value="sunglasses">Sunglasses</option>
</select>

<select class="filterby">
    <option value="all">Eyes</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="grey">Grey</option>
</select>

<div id="holder-box">
    <div class="box all 18 blue glasses"></div>
    <div class="box all 37 green sunglasses"></div>
    <div class="box all 55 grey glasses"></div>
    <div class="box all 22 brown sunglasses"></div>
    <div class="box all 47 blue glasses"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this code is also doing nothing... You want to filter by age or that your current code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update with the code:

```js
jQuery("select.filterby").change(function() {
    var filters = jQuery.map(jQuery("select.filterby").not(".age").toArray(), function(e) {
        return jQuery(e).val();
    }).join(".");
 
 var $selectedDivs = jQuery(document).find(".box." + filters);
 $selectedDivs = filterByAge($selectedDivs);
    jQuery(document).find(".box").hide(0);
    $selectedDivs.show(0)
});

function filterByAge(objectToFilter){
 var value = jQuery("select.filterby.age").val();
 if(value == "all"){
  return objectToFilter;
 }
 var minMax = value.split("-");
 var min = minMax[0];
 var max = minMax[1];
 
 return objectToFilter.filter(function (){
  var age = jQuery(this).data("age");
  return age >= min && age < max;
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="filterby age">
    <option value="all">All ages</option>
    <option value="18-25">18 to 25</option>
    <option value="25-35">26 to 35</option>
    <option value="36-45">36 to 45</option>
    <option value="46-55">46 to 55</option>
    <option value="56-65">56 to 65</option>
</select>

<select class="filterby">
    <option value="all">Show all</option>
    <option value="glasses">Glasses</option>
    <option value="sunglasses">Sunglasses</option>
</select>

<select class="filterby">
    <option value="all">Eyes</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="grey">Grey</option>
</select>

<div class="box all blue glasses" data-age="18">box all 18 blue glasses</div>
<div class="box all green sunglasses" data-age="37">box all 37 green sunglasses</div>
<div class="box all grey glasses" data-age="55">box all 55 grey glasses</div>
<div class="box all brown sunglasses" data-age="22">box all 22 brown sunglasses</div>
<div class="box all blue glasses" data-age="47">box all 47 blue glasses</div>
```

Comment: Ignacio i have updated the code so you can see what i mean.

Comment: Check the answer, you've it there